# How to force logback to create a new file on rollover

Tags: java, logback

I'm trying to achieve with logback the same thing that currently works with log4j - a size and time base rolling file appender.
Upon rolling a new file should be created with the current timestamp but logback still writes to the old file.

I'm using something like:

```
<timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="yyyyMMddkkmmss"/> 

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"> 
  <file>${logback.PREFIX}-${bySecond}.log</file> 
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"> 
    <fileNamePattern>${logback.PREFIX}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern> 
    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP"> 
        <maxFileSize>1GB</maxFileSize> 
    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy> 
  </rollingPolicy>
```

Wanted behaviour:

- application starts with *my-20131206105823.log*
- a rolling event occurs (1GB or midnight)
- the *my-2013-12-06.0.log.gz* file is created
- the application resumes logging in *my-20131207000001.log*

Current behavior:

- application starts with *my-20131206105823.log*
- a rolling event occurs (1GB or midnight)
- the *my-2013-12-06.0.log.gz* file is created
- the application resumes logging in *my-20131206105823.log*

It would be nice if I would also find out how to have this done only on the day rollover and not on the size, but this could be enough.

Java 1.7 with logback-1.0.9

Comment: Just as an update, there is a way to make the appender roll the active file as well: omit the <file> argument which means the appender will always write in the file defined by fileNamePattern. But that still does not achieve my wanted behavior.

Comment: In the end I ended up extending TimeBasedRolling policy to accept an additional activeFilename parameter (similar to fileNamePattern) and is used to change the active file name. I would love to find out if there was a simpler/cleaner way to do this and still keep archiving working correctly with the different filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure but let me try to resolve it. Once the rolling event occurred, the content of "my-20131206105823.log" file get copied to "my-2013-12-06.0.log.gz" and you will again get the new file with the same old name i,e "my-20131206105823.log".

```
<file>${logback.PREFIX}-${bySecond}.log</file>
```

$bySecond get assigned just once when you start your application, It won't change on every rollback. Timestamp is just a variable. Check [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#uniquelyNamed)

Also check this [one](https://github.com/abdulwaheed18/Slf4jTutorial/blob/master/sample7.xml).

Comment: Indeed, that's the problem. One way to do it is to extend the RollingFileAppender and create the new file on each rollover event. I was thinking there might be a logback configuration setting allowing this considering that all other variables are only initialized once.